# Can't compile VUE.JS with 'npm run dev' and 'npm run watch' command

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, npm, npm-run

I'm working on a project which is already developed by someone. The project is working fine but the thing is I need to make a few changes to vue code and to observe those changes I need to run the 'npm run dev'/'watch' command but I'm getting the following error while trying to execute it.

PS. I'm new to this platform any hint or suggestion would make my work easy. Thanks.

```
    > @ dev C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\New folder\project
> npm run development


> @ development C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\New folder\project
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

The system cannot find the path specified.
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12) {
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn node_modules\\webpack\\bin\\webpack.js',
  path: 'node_modules\\webpack\\bin\\webpack.js',
  spawnargs: [
    '--progress',
    '--hide-modules',
    '--config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-03T05_42_28_330Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-03T05_42_28_383Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you make an `npm install` ?

Comment: It clearly says what's the problem, "Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?"

Comment: @EstusFlask the node_module is already there..

Comment: @Aurel yeah same error

Comment: It's unknown how node_modules was created. Try to delete and install again. Make sure with your eyes that file C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\New folder\project\node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js exists because it's expected, you can see this in provided info

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted the node module folder and after running the 'npm install' command I was successfully able to solve this issue. Previously I was running that command but I think I was quitting the operation in between, that's the reason it was throwing the error.